# Android ROOM: When Inseting new data I get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)

Tags: android, foreign-keys, android-room

I know many have asked regarding this  FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY) error, but my problem is slightly different.  I have two entities student and record. I am able to add student, but when I add corresponding record for that student I get this error. First I add student details, then I add student record details.

student POJO class

```
@Entity(tableName = "student_table")
public class Student {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "student_id")
    private int id;

    private String studentName;

    private String studentFatherName;

    private String studentSurname;
```

record POJO class

```
    @Entity(tableName = "newRecord_table", indices = @Index("recordId"),
            foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Student.class, parentColumns = "student_id",childColumns = "recordId",
                    onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE, onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE))

    public class NewRecord {

        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        @ColumnInfo(name = "newRecordId")
        private int id;

        public int recordId;
        public string address;
        public string mobile;
```

student DAO class

```
@Dao
public interface StudentDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    void addStudent (Student student);

    @Update
    void updateStudent (Student student);

    @Delete
    void deleteStudent (Student student);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM student_table ORDER BY studentName ASC")
    LiveData<List<Student>> getAllStudents();

    @Query("DELETE FROM student_table")
    void deleteAllStudents();
}
```

record DAO class

```
@Dao
public interface NewRecordDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public void addRecord (NewRecord newRecord);

    @Update(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public void updateRecord (NewRecord newRecord);

    @Delete
    public void deleteRecord (NewRecord newRecord);

    @Query("DELETE FROM newRecord_table")
    void deleteAllRecords();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM newRecord_table ORDER BY NRdate DESC")
    LiveData<List<NewRecord>> getAllRecord();
}
```

student repository class

```
public class StudentRepository {
    private StudentDAO studentDAO;
    private LiveData<List<Student>> allStudents;

    public StudentRepository (Application application){
        StudentDatabase database = StudentDatabase.getInstance(application);
        studentDAO = database.studentDAO();
        allStudents = studentDAO.getAllStudents();
    }
     public void addStudent (Student student){
        new addStudentAsyncTask(studentDAO).execute(student);

     }
 public static class addStudentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <Student,Void,Void>{
        private StudentDAO studentDAO;
        private addStudentAsyncTask (StudentDAO studentDAO){
            this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Student... students) {
            studentDAO.addStudent(students[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

record repository class

```
public class NewRecordRepository {

    private NewRecordDAO newRecordDAO;
    private LiveData<List<NewRecord>> allRecords;
    private LiveData<List<NewRecord>> allRecordByStudent;

    public NewRecordRepository (Application application){
        StudentDatabase database = StudentDatabase.getInstance(application);
        newRecordDAO = database.newRecordDAO();
        allRecords = newRecordDAO.getAllRecord();

    }

    public void addRecord (NewRecord newRecord){
        new addRecordAsyncTask(newRecordDAO).execute(newRecord);
    }
 public static class addRecordAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<NewRecord,Void,Void> {
        private NewRecordDAO newRecordDAO;
        private addRecordAsyncTask (NewRecordDAO newRecordDAO){
            this.newRecordDAO = newRecordDAO;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(NewRecord... newRecords) {

// LOG shows: this is where it re direct me this is where the problem lies.
            newRecordDAO.addRecord(newRecords[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

lastly database class

```
@Database(entities = {Student.class, NewRecord.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class StudentDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static StudentDatabase instance;

    public abstract StudentDAO studentDAO();

    public abstract NewRecordDAO newRecordDAO();

    public static synchronized StudentDatabase getInstance(Context context){
        if ( instance == null ){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    StudentDatabase.class,"students_DB")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

MY LOG:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
>       Process: com.timelessfusionapps.hifztasmee, PID: 12833
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
>           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>        Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:796)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>           at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
>           at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insert(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:64)
>           at com.timelessfusionapps.hifztasmee.DOA.NewRecordDAO_Impl.addRecord(NewRecordDAO_Impl.java:242)
>           at com.timelessfusionapps.hifztasmee.Repository.NewRecordRepository$addRecordAsyncTask.doInBackground(NewRecordRepository.java:61)
>           at com.timelessfusionapps.hifztasmee.Repository.NewRecordRepository$addRecordAsyncTask.doInBackground(NewRecordRepository.java:54)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when call `addRecord` newRecord object need to have recordid set for student_id that been added.

If does

```
    NewRecord n1 = new NewRecord();

    n1.address = "xxx";
    n1.mobile = "0000000000";
    n1.NRDate = "2020-01-01 10:30";
    newRecordRepository.addRecord(n1);
```

failures like

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY)
```

changes to give proper recordId like

```
    NewRecord n1 = new NewRecord();
    n1.recordId = 1;
    n1.address = "xxx";
    n1.mobile = "0000000000";
    n1.NRDate = "2020-01-01 10:30";
    newRecordRepository.addRecord(n1);
```

working. 1 ok for showing test, you need proper student when do real

Comment: I understood what you trying to say, but where exactly I have to implement this logic, when I implement this logic in my add record activity, it still gives me same error, and when I add this logic in repository class, the recycler view is not showing any data

Comment: @sulli110 very important getting proper student to be passing when call addRecord, how getting not seen in code you give

Comment: I got the ID value from studentviewmodel.getallstudents.getvalue.get(position).getId();
Thats how I got id and now it is working.